# How to convert a structure to an internal table dynamically

Tags: structure, abap, internal-tables

I'm trying to create a method that will import a structure assuming that all structure elements are flat and the same data type.  Then I want to convert it to a table with that type dynamically and return it.  Where should I start?  I've been trying to get this to work for several hours and am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `create_dynamic_table` form using `cl_alv_table_create` like so:

```
* Create dynamic internal table and assign to FS
  CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
    EXPORTING
      it_fieldcatalog  = ifc
      i_length_in_byte = 'X' "added by Paul Robert Oct 28, 2009 17:04
    IMPORTING
      ep_table         = dy_table.
  ASSIGN dy_table->* TO <dyn_table>.
* Create dynamic work area and assign to FS
  CREATE DATA dy_line LIKE LINE OF <dyn_table>.
  ASSIGN dy_line->* TO <dyn_wa>.
```

[Here](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Dynamic+Internal+table) is a link that will help you get started.

Comment: This has been flagged for removal as a link-only answer (it won't be useful if the link goes dead, which unfortunately happens all the time). Could you please edit this to include the necessary information in the answer itself? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**There is absolutely no need to use `CL_ALV_TABLE_CREATE`** - pure overkill. Use the [Run Time Type Services (RTTS)](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenrtti.htm) to get information about your input data (and validate your assumption about the component types), then use the [dynamic form of CREATE TABLE](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapcreate_data_itab.htm):

```
* asssuming that l_type_name contains the type name of a single element
  CREATE DATA lr_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF (l_type_name).
```